# How can i show the data in angular component after authentication is done in a Pop up window?

Tags: angular

I  have to do the authentication in angular by GitLab. So i have created a button in my angular-app. After click on that button this function will be call the login() which will open a pop up. After log in successfully i got the access token by which i will get the data from GitLab.

```
  isLoggedIn = true;
  api: any;
  public test: any;
  accessToken: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private gitLabApi: GitLabApiService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (this.accessToken) {
      this.apiRequest();
    } else {
      let fragMent = this.route.snapshot.fragment; // only update on component creation
      this.accessToken = fragMent.split('=')[1].split('&')[0];
      if (this.accessToken || this.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', this.accessToken);
      }
      window.close();
      this.router.navigate(['manager']);
      this.apiRequest();
    }

  }
  logOut() {
    if (this.accessToken) {
      console.log(localStorage.removeItem('access_token'));
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
      this.router.navigate(['logginIn']);
    }

    this.sideBar.afterLogIn = false;
  }


  apiRequest() {
    this.gitLabApi.getProjectApi(this.accessToken).subscribe(
      apiData => {
        this.api = apiData;
        // console.log(this.api);
        this.cd.markForCheck();
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      },
      error => console.log(error.message)
    );
    this.sideBar.getCommitDetail();
    this.sideBar.afterLogIn = true;
  }

  logIn() {
    //window.location.href = authUrl;
    window.open(authUrl, "pop Up", "width=250, height= 250 ")
  }
```

But after closing the pop up in ngOnInit, its not redirect to my page. 
Instead of `window.open` if i use `window.location.href` then its working fine. Now how can i achieve the same functionality with `window.open` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this [ng-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/?gclid=CjwKCAiAiarfBRASEiwAw1tYv3mfjX3CMQKkB3-bIi3DTQwRqIdGOehZ1Y7BEqxKxUeTuNdMuiI0CxoCe5EQAvD_BwE#/modals)

Comment: actually i am not looking any css. I want to do the authentication in my pop up window. Here nothing to do with the css i guess

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `window.close` is closing the window which the router then tries to navigate. You need the logIn method to handle the routing logic for the original instance of the app once the login window is closed. Example:

```js
logIn() {
  const newwindow = window.open(authUrl, "pop Up", "width=250, height= 250 ");

  newwindow.onbeforeunload = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
      this.router.navigate(['manager']);
      this.apiRequest();
    } else {
      // login failed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi  unfortunently its not working. Before windows is closing or user logged in, ` newwindow.onbeforeunload = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
      this.router.navigate(['manager']);
      this.apiRequest();
    } else {
      // login failed
    }
  }` this line of code is executing. @teddy-sterne